# Find the curve, given that $r'(t) = Cr(t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, 3d, curves

I need to find the curve, given that $r'(t) = Cr(t)$ (where $C$ is a constant), for all real $t$ and $r(0)=i+2j+3k$.

To start, I know that the equation I will need is the 
$$K=\frac{||r'(t) \times r''(t)||}{||r'(t)||^3}.$$

However, I'm not sure how to get what I currently have $(r'(t))$ into $r(t)$ so that I can plug the values into the equation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can solve $r(t)$ explicitly (solving the ODE)

Comment: @John I haven't done calculus in quite a while, remind me of how that is possible, please?

Comment: @John what about ti+2tj+3tk? Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: You don't need that formula for $K$. Separate $r$ into components and solve for each separately; it's a simple ODE.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato But how would I solve for the actual curve by just separating r into components? Could you also give me an example of this, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "separating it into components and solving each separately"

Comment: Like mich95 did below.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Ah, okay that makes sense. Thanks. However, simply having r(t) doesn't give us the curvature. I know that using the formula for K here is extremely messy, but how else would I be able to find curvature without using it? Thank you.

Comment: Well, if you need the curvature, you should now apply the formula for curvature to the found solution. It wasn't clear that you needed it. The question said "I need to find the curve,"

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Sorry, yes, I meant the curve. I thought the curve was also found using that equation.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Ah, nevermind. I figured it out. Clearly all the calc I'd learned back in 2013 completely moved out of my brain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$r'(t)=Cr(t)$ implies $(x'(t),y'(t),z'(t))=C(x(t),y(t),z(t))$  So $x(t)=K_{1}e^{Ct}$, $y(t)=K_{2}e^{Ct}$ $z(t)=K_{3}e^{Ct}$ with $x(0)=1$, $y(0)=2$, $z(0)=3$, where $K_{1}$, $K_{2}$ $K_{3}$ re constants to determine.$x(0)=1$ then $K_{1}=1$, similarly, $K_{2}=2$, $K_{3}=3$. So I think $r(t)=e^{Ct}i+2e^{Ct}j+3e^{Ct}k$

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the curvature, then solving isn't necessary.

Note that
$$ \textbf{r}''(t) = C\textbf{r}'(t)$$

Thus
$$ K = \frac{||\textbf{r}' \times C\textbf{r}'||}{||\textbf{r}'||^3} = 0 $$